# Cannot copy files from internal storage to external SD

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, file-management

**Device:** Moto X Play Stock (6.0.1) with external SD as portable storage

- Prior to rooting (recently), transfer both ways (internal and external SD and vice versa was not a problem)
- After, rooting, it is *one way*- I can copy files only from external SD card to internal . I am assuming that external SD is not the problem since

  - Device shows external SD, so do various file managers- ES Explorer,  Total Commander and all of them fail to do this
  - External SD recognized on laptop and copying / writing is not a problem
- In Marshmallow, when you need to copy to external SD, you get a notification as below, and in the second pic you expect to see the external SD card listed and you accept- this doesn't happen, there is neither external SD shown nor option to select

[image]
[image]

- Rooting couldn't or shouldn't have caused this. Further, TWRP option of not allowing modifications to system was chosen
- I didn't mess with any system tweaks,except for installing Xposed and a few modules (**Edit** Uninstalled Xposed and behavior is same)

**What could be causing this and how to fix it?**

---

**Note:**

1. I do have access to Mint Linux but practically zero knowledge of commands. If Linux helps in solving this , please be explicit about instructions
2. There a couple of questions similar but **not** the same problem and do not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by shutting down device, removing external SD card, rebooting a couple of times, inserting external SD and starting the device

It worked but clueless as to what was wrong and what fixed it

I am hoping for a proper explanation/solution to show up